# Javascript separate punctuation from alpha-numeric chats

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I'm trying to split a string like the following in order to have a array of the n elements, for example:
`var str = "(someword,bbb)"` 
So the array would be
`var arr = ["(", "someword", ",", "bbb", ")"]`

I tried with split and regex but it actually removes those punctuation marks while I need them to be still available. Is this even possible?

Many thanks in advance

Split with punctuation regex but punctuation marks are not kept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split on capturing word characters with a capture group

```js
var str = "(someword,bbb)";
console.log(str.split(/(\w+)/));
```

You could also specify the characters to split on using a character class `[(),]` and remove empty entries if neccesary:

```js
var str = "(someword,bbb)";
console.log(str.split(/([(),])/).filter(Boolean));
```